# Access linked Sharepoint list error; Cannot reference rows created when you are disconnected from the server

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to make a split Access db with the backend as linked Sharepoint lists in Office 365.
When I try to add data using one list that is my 'Locality' reference I get the following error;

```
You cannot reference rows created when you are disconnected from the server because this violates the lookup settings defined for this table or list. Please reconnect all tables with the server and try again.
```

There seems to be a 5000 row limit on lists in O365!
If I delete *most* of the list so it is under 5000 rows, it works fine.

http://www.csgpro.com/post/110085

I'm not trying to view it - just use it as a reference.

Images here;

[Screenshots in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9zlgl07o0b16j27/AACYUs0szCkigSZHo17s_D7ta?dl=0)

Comment: So if you reconnect all your tables, then do things work?

Comment: It is not disconnected.

Something to do with 5000 item limit for lists. If I delete rows down to 5000 it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute an update, or operation on a office 365 linked SP table unless indexing can be used to reduce the update below 5000 records. This means that if the criteria used IS NOT indexed, then a full table scan occurs and you not be able to update even 50 records.

Worse is during the up-loading process there is a bug/issue in that any index set will NOT BE SET if the initial table upload was greater 5000 records. So tables can grow beyond 5000 records, and you can/should be able to execute a delete on say 100 records. However if an index cannot be used to grab the 100 records, then you get errors.

So you are correct the issue is to do with 5000 record limit. Try using the PK as a criteria (range) – you likely find the update works. (the PK is indexed even for up-loaded tables > 5000 records).

Comment: Terrible!
In this case the table is 16000 rows and is used as a lookup so it's bound to fail.
In the end I deleted all my lookups, put the data on Sharepoint and use the lookups at form level in my front end.

Advantage: Works.
Disadvantage: Reference tables cannot be adjusted globally - have to roll out new front ends to do any changes.

Major disadvantage: Lookups not available to web forms.